# ffmpeg 2nd pass segfault

Tags: ffmpeg, x264

I'm trying to get an old transcoding server up and running in a new environment and I'm experiencing some issues getting the well tested ffmpeg commands to work in the new environment.

It's a 2 pass encoding strategy, and the first pass runs just fine every time, the 2nd pass consistently fails with the following:

```
[libx264 @ 0x3925fc0] 2nd pass has more frames than 1st pass (1478)
[libx264 @ 0x3925fc0] continuing anyway, at constant QP=14
[libx264 @ 0x3925fc0] disabling adaptive B-frames
[libx264 @ 0x3925fc0] specified frame type is not compatible with max B-frames
Segmentation fault
```

Here is the command we're using for each pass:

Pass 1:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -pass 1 -b 774000 -ab 128000 -s 640x360 -passlogfile ffmpeglog -vcodec libx264 -g 90 -bf 3 -refs 1 -b_strategy 1 -coder 1 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -cmp chroma -me_range 16 -me_method dia -subq 2 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -direct-pred 3 -trellis 0 -partitions -parti8x8-parti4x4-partp8x8-partb8x8 -r 30 -keyint_min 25 -wpredp 2 -rc_lookahead 50 -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 pass1.mp4
```

Pass 2:

```
ffmpeg -y -i pass1.mp4 -pass 2 -b 774000 -ab 128000 -s 640x360 -passlogfile ffmpeglog -vcodec libx264 -g 90 -bf 3 -refs 8 -b_strategy 1 -coder 1 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -cmp chroma -me_range 16 -me_method umh -subq 9 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -direct-pred 3 -trellis 2 -partitions +parti8x8+parti4x4+partp8x8+partp4x4+partb8x8 -r 30 -keyint_min 25 -wpredp 2 -rc_lookahead 60 -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 pass2.mp4
```

...and here is my ffmpeg configuration:

```
ffmpeg version 2.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 25 2014 19:23:21 with gcc 4.6.3 (GCC) 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-version3 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      52. 48.101 / 52. 48.101
  libavcodec     55. 39.101 / 55. 39.101
  libavformat    55. 19.104 / 55. 19.104
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.100 /  3. 90.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Crap. I should have added those to Super User.

Comment: You can flag your question to get it migrated.

Comment: @MikeFlynn SuperUser or ServerFault?

Comment: @bluefeet I just did some quick research, and interestingly it appears that ffmpeg questions are split between the two. ServerFault seems to have all the ffmpeg installation questions, while SuperUser seems to have the ffmpeg usage questions. Based on that, I think SuperUser seems like the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with that seems to be working great so far: I started over again with the help of the fine folks from #ffmepg

```
ffmpeg -i $inputFile -vcodec libx264 -s $widthx$height -b $videoBitrate -preset medium -crf 23 -acodec libfaac -q:a 100 -movflags +faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -r $frameRate $outputFile
```